# How to execute foreach in Dart?

Tags: dart

I entered the data from json, everything works fine, but now only the first element is displayed. How can I write here like foreach so that all elements with a loop are displayed.

[You can see the code here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1110827/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-foreach-%D0%B2-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5-dart-flutter)

Comment: you need to be clear on what you wanna achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the data with listview builder.
Try code something like this:

```
...
else if(snapshot.hasData ){
    return ListView.builder (
        itemCount: snapshot.data.length, \\length of snapshot data
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
          return Container(              
               child:Column(
                children: <Widget>[

                  new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0)),  

                  new Container(                                                
                      child: new Text(                           
                       'Тип штрафа:  ${data[index]['VDescription']}'                         
                        ),
                  ),
                  new Container(                                                
                      child: new Text(                           
                       'Адрес:  ${data[index]['VLocation']}'                         
                        ),
                  ),
                  new Container(                                                
                      child: new Text(                           
                       'Дата:  ${data[index]['VTime']}'                         
                        ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
           );
        }
    );
```

I hope this will work. :)